# JCR Login - remote error: tls: unrecognized name

Tags: docker, terminal, jcr

i am trying to login in JCR to push the image in Repo but while log in i am getting Blow  error.

```
docker login -u user -p pass123* 10.0.2.103:8082
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get "https://localhost:port/v2/": remote error: tls: unrecognized name
```

I have tried `reverse proxy and installed JCR on Docker` but didn't work.